# What's the difference between example.com/controller and example.com/controller/ in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a PostsController, not essential to the example but will help when I paste snippets, and I'm using `current_page?` to, as the name implies, figure out what page is being displayed. I'm getting what seem like weird results.

`current_page?` will return different answers if I go to `/posts` vs. `/posts/`.

As a test, on the index view for my controller I am simply calling

```
current_page?(:action => 'index')
```

If I go to /controller (with no trailing slash), `current_page?` will return true. However, if I go to /controller/, it will return false.

Tailing the log shows that both do in fact hit the same action

```
Processing PostsController#index (for 127.0.0.1 at 2009-08-11 18:28:12) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"index", "method"=>:get, "controller"=>"posts"}
```

The action produces the same results for both, as to be expected.

I'm using Rails 2.3.2 and [this ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2218-current_page-in-rails-222-delivers-wrong-results) is the only thing that seems close. The only commenter thinks that current_page should "consider two URLs to be the same page if they both refer to the same RESTful object".

Thanks for any insight into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rails routing will **tolerate** the trailing slash but it will not be generated when you pass `:action => 'index', :controller => 'posts'` to `url_for` (with *standard* routes).

according to current_page? [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F) it just generates a url from the passed arguments and then compares to the current request url **string**. since  this generated url will not have the trailing slash it will return true when current url is /controller and false when /controller/

There are several ways you can solve your problem:

- compare the params, not generated url
- redirect from /controller/ to /controller. This is actually a good idea if you do page caching etc. also for SEO
- I'm sure there are other ways as always :)

Comment: That makes sense. Should have probably checked the source of current_page? Thank you very much!