# Navigation menu in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my navigation menu in application.html and the menu has class="active" . That depends on the page the user is on. How can I dynamically figure out which item needs to have the class:

Here's how my top menu bar is:

```
<ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Page3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perhaps this SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1751863/22371) will help, or check out the [Tabs on Rails](http://github.com/weppos/tabs_on_rails) gem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to have an @active_page instance variable in the controllers, which you set on each action. You may also do this already with a title (@title maybe?), so perhaps you could use that instead. Then in the template:

```
<li class="<%= "active" if @active_page == "Home" %>">...</li>
```

Comment: Would be better with `@controller.controller_name` and `@controller.action_name` no?

Comment: @hachpai - that's another way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest (and possibly the most rudimentary) is to use `current_page?`. You can [read up in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F) to see how it works. As [I've experienced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263369/whats-the-difference-between-example-com-controller-and-example-com-controller), it does not always produce what you want.

There is also a gem, [navigasmic](https://github.com/jejacks0n/navigasmic), which works pretty well if your needs get fairly complex.

There are a number of ways to accomplish what you are trying to do. Try out `current_page?` first and if you find yourself ripping your hair out, move on to something like navigasmic.

Comment: i have always been seeing that current page in my ide intelligence but never relly knew it was

Answer (score 0):

you can create a siple helper like this

```
  def  nav_link(name, url)
    selected = url.all? { |key, value| params[key] == value }
    link_to(name, url, :class => (selected ? "youarehere tabs" : "tabs"))
  end

<div id="tabs" class="tabs2">
  <%= nav_link %>
  <%= nav_link %>
  <%= nav_linl  %>
</div>
```

then add the necessary css styles